# Call function to output contents of array

Tags: arrays, function, powershell, get-childitem

I'm new to Powershell, i am working with the basics. If someone could try provide an example of;

A function to get contents of a folder (`get-childitem -Path c:\temp | Select-Object Name, Length`) and puts them into an array of arrays -- `array=@()`

The script body should then output what is returned from the function. I can use a for loop to make a table format of my array which is ok.

I believe a variable scope comes in here, to return the contents of an array?

In simple terms the Function needs to do something, and outside of the function needs a variable scope to retain what `get-childitem` returns.

So output needs to be called outside of the function.

Example:
Function - Get-childItem - Store Data in Array 
Call Function to Output Data in Array.

Comment: Im lost on what is wrong here. Functions will return everything that is sent to the output stream. Do you want to guarantee and array is returned? `function GCI{get-childitem -Path c:\temp | Select-Object Name, Length}` would return an array (if there is more that one result also depends on your PowerShell version)

Comment: yes i want to create an array in a function and then be able to call it outside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is this then

```
function doSomething {get-childitem -Path c:\temp | Select-Object Name, Length}

$array = @()
$array = doSomething
```